# Ruby on Rails access whole params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that deals with user rotas - and I'm currently adding the ability for admin approvals. If the user updates their own rota the params hash looks something like:

Parameters: {id:1, role_id: 1, team_id:1, rota: [startDate: 01/01/2014, endDate:02/02/2014]}

and these are submitted using a form with:

```
<%= form_for [@team,@role,@rota] do |f| %>
form code
<% end %>
```

We need to access the attributes outside the rota: object but currently can't find a way to as:

params.require requires you to pass an object in.

My team members have decided to add hidden fields to submit the attributes within the rota object but that seems redundant seeing as they are quite clearly there, we just can't find a way to access them, and ideas?

Comment: Help me understand, why not just pass a form for user, permitting specific strong parameters?

Comment: We are passing a form, but the parameters sent from said form appear outside any object in the params hash.So we are trying to access them.

Comment: I'll try to provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was talking about something like

```
def user_rota_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:role_id, :team_id, :rota => [:startDate, :endDate])
end
```

Then, for your nested attributes you could use `fields_for`.
Your form, thus, should look something this (omitting labels and keeping it basic):

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :role_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :team_id %>
    <%= f.fields_for :rota do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.date_field :startDate %>
        <%= ff.date_field :endDate %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If we don't specify the rota and rota in the form it complains about the route being invalid.

Comment: Are you using nested routes then?

Comment: Yes, we have our route for this page looks like: 

Team/1/Role/1/Rota/1/Edit

Comment: Your params should look like this `params={:role => {:id=>1}, :team=>{:id=>1}, :rota=>{:startDate=>"..", :endDate=>".."}}`... Access them like `params[:role][:id]`, `params[:team][:id]`, `params[:rota][:startDate]` and `params[:rota][endDate]`